How to mount a ZFS encrypted dataset to be available for only one user?
In Ubuntu 22.04, I've created an encrypted dataset hdd/enc and for privacy reasons I need it to be available only for me. Every time the system gets rebooted, it's ok for me to enter the password I never store anywhere manually by mount -a -l and entering the passphrase. But since others may ssh to my system and view their files and have sudo privilege and even have root password of my system because of the company's policies, they may view my private files too. I was using encfs, but I think it's a better idea to use the builtin capabilities of zfs instead. The encfs limits access of others even root to the folder I encrypt. I need to know whether the zfs encryption also has this ability?

They may view and edit my files as I do. I need a private folder.

Cross posted in https://superuser.com/q/1838933/629249

My initial answer was wrong, since ZFS and probably other file-level decryption technologies does indeed decrypt for all users with access once the passkey is loaded.
To encrypt and decrypt exclusively for the current user, you have to use user-space encryption like EncFS.
Also see this Q&A.

This is what I know. After I mount the dataset, the data gets unlocked and everyone with access to my system may view my files too. encfs limits the access to the one who has unlocked the directory. I need this to happen to zfs dataset too. If it has not the capability, please let me know what is my other choices.
